# Wrong number of arguments on method.invoke

Tags: java, arrays

I currently have this code:

```
public class Pants {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pants pants = new Pants();
        pants.eat(10, 10.3, "Nice.");

        Object[] params = {(long)10, 10.3, "Nice."};
        Method eatMethod = pants.getClass().getMethods()[0];
        try
        {
            eatMethod.invoke(pants, params);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void eat(long amount, double size, String name) {
        System.out.println("You ate");
    }
}
```

It always throws

```
IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments.
```

This happened with other methods too. I used the same parameters in `eat()` as in `method.invoke`, and the types are the same. The error is thrown on

```
eatMethod.invoke(pants, params);
```

Comment: Didn't it give you a line number for the error?

Comment: `Method eatMethod = pants.getClass().getMethods()[0];` are you sure `eat` is the first one?

Comment: Please show your `Pants` class. Also, getting a method like that `getMethods()[0]` is a bad idea - you never know which one you will get.

Comment: The code is working fine for me.

Comment: It is thrown on eatMethod.invoke(pants, params). That is the entire class, I know that getMethods()[0] is a bad idea but it was just for testing, to keep it short.

Comment: Try and do a `System.out.println(eatMethod.getName())` before calling `invoke()`

Comment: Well then, now you know that this bad idea is the problem you're having, and you can't test that way even if you wish to keep it short.

Comment: Just for debugging, try printing `eatMethod.getName()`. You may be surprised. As an aside, there is no need to cast a literal number with `(long)`. Just write `10L`.

Comment: getMethods()[0] returns you the main() method, you should be using the getMethods()[1] if you are trying to access eat() method. Better still use getDeclaredMethod(methodname, params) to get the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments say. We don't know wich method is `pants.getClass().getMethods()[0]`. Try to get the  name with `eatMethod.getName()` and see if is really the method eat. If
not you can try with this.

```
 java.lang.reflect.Method method;
     method = pants.getClass().getMethod("eat", Long.class, Double.class, String.class);
    .
    .
    .
      method.invoke(pants,params );
```

Also... Checking the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) The methods are never sorted

> The elements in the returned array are not sorted and are not in any
>   particular order.

So sometimes your code might work and sometimes not.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that when I used `getMethods()[0]`, I was getting the main method and calling that, which obviously has no parameters so it didn't work. Ideally I should've used

```
getMethod("eat", long.class, double.class, String.class)
```

which does work.